# Solve the following ODE $y''=\sqrt{1+y'^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve this ODE but I don't know how.
I have an exam next week and this exercise will be on it.
Please help me:

$y''=\sqrt{1+y'^2}$

Comment: This can be reduced to a separable form. What have you tried ?

Comment: Put $z=y'$ to reduce it to a simple first order DE.

Comment: Write it as $$\frac{y''(x)}{\sqrt{1+(y'(x))^2}}=1$$ and integrate

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch You forgot a square in the denominator!

Comment: @Fakemistake Thank you, fixed

Comment: Hint: $\text{arshinh}(y')-\text{arshinh}(y'_0)=x-x_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lry $p=\frac{dy}{dx}$, the the ODE is $$\frac{dp}{dx}=\sqrt{1+p^2} \implies \frac{dp}{\sqrt{1+p^2}}=dx \implies \int \frac{dp}{\sqrt{1+p^2}}= \int dx +C.$$
$$\implies \sinh^{-1} p =(x+C) \implies p=\sinh (x+C) \implies \frac{dy}{dx}= \sinh (x+c)$$ $$\implies \int dy =\int \sinh (x+C) dx \implies y= \cosh(x+C)+D$$

Comment: but if i want to know p with this form:
ln(sqrt(p^2+1)+p)=x+c
how can solve to find p?

Comment: Oh! please see we have already found $p=\sinh(x+C)$!